# Using angular-material's md-checkbox to replace ui-grid's select box

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ui-grid

I want to use angular-material's md-checkbox to replace ui-grid's select box,but the `ng-model` of `grid.selection.selectAll` is uncorrect here is my code :

```
'use strict';
angular.module "myApp"
.run ['$templateCache'
  ($templateCache) ->       
    $templateCache.put('ui-grid/selectionRowHeaderButtons',
      "<div class=\"ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons \" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}\" >" +
        "<md-checkbox style=\"margin: 0; vertical-align: middle\"  ng-model=\"row.isSelected\" ng-click=\"row.isSelected=!row.isSelected;selectButtonClick(row, $event)\"></md-checkbox>
        &nbsp;
      </div>"
    );
    $templateCache.put('ui-grid/selectionSelectAllButtons',
      "<div class=\"ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons \" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-all-selected': grid.selection.selectAll}\" ng-if=\"grid.options.enableSelectAll\">
        <md-checkbox style=\"margin: 0; vertical-align: middle\" type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=\"grid.selection.selectAll\" ng-click=\"grid.selection.selectAll=!grid.selection.selectAll;headerButtonClick($event)\"></md-checkbox>
      </div>"
    );
]
```

when I click the checkbox of `selectionSelectAllButtons` it doesn't work
[image]

and after I cancel the select, it select all the rows
[image]

here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nn7eWnY1ZwbnWO7oDVJl?p=preview)

**If I use `<input type='checkbox'>`** ,it works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change templateCache as below, it works well.

`$templateCache.put('ui-grid/selectionRowHeaderButtons', "<div class=\"ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons \" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}\" >" + "<md-checkbox style=\"margin: 0; vertical-align: middle\"  ng-model=\"row.isSelected\" ng-click=\"selectButtonClick(row, $event);row.isSelected=!row.isSelected\"></md-checkbox> &nbsp; </div>");
      $templateCache.put('ui-grid/selectionSelectAllButtons', "<div class=\"ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons \" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-all-selected': grid.selection.selectAll}\" ng-if=\"grid.options.enableSelectAll\"> <md-checkbox style=\"margin: 0; vertical-align: middle\" type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=\"grid.selection.selectAll\" ng-click=\"headerButtonClick($event);grid.selection.selectAll=!grid.selection.selectAll\"></md-checkbox> </div>");`

Here is Plunkle (https://plnkr.co/edit/0tO8VZrV0yAq0LHiY0rk?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
'$templateCache', function($templateCache) {

  $templateCache.put('ui-grid/selectionRowHeaderButtons', "<div class=\"ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons \" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}\" >" + "<md-checkbox style=\"margin: 0; vertical-align: middle\"  ng-model=\"row.isSelected\" ng-click=\"row.isSelected=!row.isSelected;selectButtonClick(row, $event)\"></md-checkbox> &nbsp; </div>");
  $templateCache.put('ui-grid/selectionSelectAllButtons', "<div class=\"ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons \" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-all-selected': grid.selection.selectAll}\" ng-if=\"grid.options.enableSelectAll\"> <md-checkbox style=\"margin: 0; vertical-align: middle\" type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=\"row.isSelected=grid.selection.selectAll\"  ng-click=\"grid.selection.selectAll=grid.selection.selectAll;headerButtonClick($event)\"></md-checkbox> </div>");
}
```

this will sometimes work